# Why does my UI look like 16.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gui

I run ubuntu 22.04.
I checked it by running `lsb_release -a`

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

But a few days ago, after rebooting my laptop, it looked like a 16.04 desktop. I look in System Settings and it indeed shows "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS". Altough when I look it up in gnome-version (`cat /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml`) it says 42.5.0

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gnome-version>
 <platform>42</platform>
 <minor>5</minor>
 <micro>0</micro>
 <distributor>Ubuntu</distributor>
 <!--<date></date>-->
</gnome-version>
```

What went wrong? How can I restore the default 22.04 look and feel?
[Here is what my desktop looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz6oB.jpg)

Comment: `But a few days ago, after rebooting my laptop`  -- Did you make any changes before rebooting? Also, can you post a screenshot by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1443990/edit) the question?

Comment: how did you install 22.04.1 or did you upgrade from an older version of ubuntu.if you have v22.04 installed there is no easy way to downgrade to v16.04 so there must be some information missing from your question.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi the screenshot is in the link

Comment: @trondhansen I've been upgrading this system since 18.04 was out. It came pre-installed with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

Apparently when I logged in Ubuntu choose to use Unity desktop manager. When I switch to Ubuntu:wayland everything looks familiar again and the settings show gnome 42.5 Wayland.